# Setting the mouse tracking speed via applescript

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, applescript

I'm trying to get an apple script to set the mouse tracking speed in OS X 10.6, specifically with a new Magic Mouse.

I've found the following:

```
set trackingValue to 5

--Open and activate System Preferences
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

--Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        try
            --Open the "Keyboard & Mouse" pane
            click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            delay 2
            set value of slider 1 to trackingValue
            --end tell
        on error theError
            --An error occured
            display dialog ("Sorry, an error occured while altering Keyboard and Mouse settings:" & return & theError) buttons "OK" default button "OK"
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

But it seems to be built for 10.5 as I get an error when trying to 'set value of slider 1 to trackingValue'

2 questions...

1. How can I get this to work with the 10.6/Magic Mouse combo?
2. How would I go about getting the name of the [slider on the control panel](http://reljac.com/so_1/Mouse.jpg), or any other control for that matter, for use in applescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things here - firstly, you need to have checked the "`Enable access for assistive devices`" in `System Preferences / Universal Access / Mouse & Trackpad`.  Obviously you've already done this, otherwise the script wouldn't get to where it is without already failing, but it's an important step for anyone else trying to get this working.

Secondly, the problem with the line you were receiving the error on was that you weren't telling the AppleScript where to find the slider you were wanting to change the value of.  By changing the line to the following, the script started working:

```
set value of slider "Tracking Speed" of window "Mouse" to trackingValue
```

Note that as well as naming the window to be used by the AppleScript I have also named the slider to be used as well.  Whilst running Snow Leopard and using "slider 1", the second slider in the window "Scrolling Speed" was being altered.  So, by using the name of the slider rather than its number we bypass any possible indexing issues. As for working out the name of the slider? I simply tried using the value of the label that went with it, which worked in this instance. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Thus, the final script becomes:

```
set trackingValue to 5

--Open and activate System Preferences
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

--Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        try
            --Open the "Keyboard & Mouse" pane
            click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            delay 2
            set value of slider "Tracking Speed" of window "Mouse" to trackingValue
            --end tell
        on error theError
            --An error occured
            display dialog ("Sorry, an error occured while altering Keyboard and Mouse settings:" & return & theError) buttons "OK" default button "OK"
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I had to make on change...
set value of slider "Tracking" of window "Mouse" to trackingValue
...but otherwise your script did the trick.  Thanks

Comment: Script worked for me without any edits.  Nicely done and nicely explained!

Comment: it also worked for me when I used: set value of slider "Tracking" of window "Mouse" to trackingValue. A very good example.. Thanx :) One question - can you tell us similar script to set: action of right mouse pop-up button to secondary button action?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mavericks 10.9 there is an extra tab group you need to consider, this script works:

```
set trackingValue to 8

--Open and activate System Preferences
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

--Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        try
            --Open the "Keyboard & Mouse" pane
            click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            delay 2

            tell tab group 1 of window "Mouse"
                set value of slider "Tracking" to trackingValue
            end tell
            --end tell
        on error theError
            --An error occured
            display dialog ("Sorry, an error occured while altering Keyboard and Mouse settings:" & return & theError) buttons "OK" default button "OK"
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The script still functions as intended with OS X Lion 10.7.  One small change I added after setting the Tracking Speed  value is:

```
        set value of slider "Tracking Speed" of window "Mouse" to trackingValue
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        --end tell
```

This closes System Preferences so I'm not left looking at a menu pane and can get back to my work with my mouse's now speedier tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's suggestion seems not working in 10.8. I tried to replace "Tracking Speed" with "Tracking", the value was not set correspondently.

Wonder they've changed the name of the slider or not.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Sierra OS X machine.  If you get an error, you may have to slightly lengthen one or both of the script delays to better match the speed your machine.

```
set trackingValue to 8

--Open and activate System Preferences
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

--Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        try
            delay 1
            --Open the "Mouse" pane
            click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            delay 0.5
            tell window "Mouse"
                set value of slider "Tracking speed" to trackingValue
            end tell
        on error theError
            --An error occured
            display dialog ("Sorry, an error occured while altering Mouse settings:" & return & theError) buttons "OK" default button "OK"
        end try
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reason those scripts were not working in OS X 10.10. Needed a little tweaking but now it works.

```
set trackingValue to 9

--Open and activate System Preferences
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
--Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell tab group 1 of window "Mouse"
            set value of slider "Tracking" to trackingValue
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Enjoy.